# How can I use Java objects as data sets in Eclipse BIRT?

Tags: java, reporting, birt

I basically followed this tutorial: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseBIRT/article.html

Now I have two Java classes, `Mock` and `MockContainer`, that look like this:

```
package reports;

public class Mock {

    private int x;
    private double y;

    public Mock(int x, double y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public double getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public void setY(double y) {
        this.y = y;
    }

}
```

...

```
package reports;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MockContainer {

    public MockContainer() {

    }

    public List<Mock> getMockList() {
        List<Mock> mocks = new ArrayList<Mock>();

        mocks.add(new Mock(1000, +2.5));
        mocks.add(new Mock(2000, +1.5));
        mocks.add(new Mock(3000, +0.5));
        mocks.add(new Mock(3000, -0.5));
        mocks.add(new Mock(2000, -1.5));
        mocks.add(new Mock(1000, -2.5));

        return mocks;
    }

}
```

Also, I have a *Scripted Data Source* `data_source` and a *Data Set* `data_set` with two columns, `x` (Integer) and `y` (Decimal).

But I have problems writing the JavaScripts. My JavaScripts `open` and `fetch` in `data_set` look like this:

```
count = 0;

mockContainer = new Packages.reports.MockContainer();

mockList = mockContainer.getMockList();
```

...

```
if (count < mockList.size()) {
    row["x"] = mockList.get(count).getX();
    row["y"] = mockList.get(count).getY();

    count++;

    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

But *Preview Results* stays empty...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why the results are not shown in the preview, but at the end it works...